# How to prove $1-[(1-\frac{1}{N})^n] < \frac{n}{N}$

Tags: inequality

I have this probability problem from college that i figured out the reasoning behind it and now I'm stuck with this inequality that seems just impossible for me to prove. Could anyone help me, please?
$$
1 - \biggl[ \Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{N}\Bigr)^n \biggr] < \frac{n}{N}
$$

Conditions from the problem: $N>n>1$; $n$ and $N$ are both natural numbers.

PS: I already posted a question about the probability problem behind this inequality, but now I wanted to post and ask specifically about the inequality. If that's wrong, please just let me know so I'll delete it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: write it as $\,(1-\frac{1}{N})^n \gt 1-\frac{n}{N}\,$ and lookup [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks dxiv!

Bernoulli's inequality: $(1+x)^r \ge 1+rx$ for every integer $r \ge 1$ and real number $x \gt -1$.

Let $-\frac{1}{N}$ be $x$, which is greater than $-1$, and $n$ be $r$, since $n$ is a natural number:

$(1-\frac{1}{N})^n \ge 1-\frac{n}{N}$

Multiply both sides by (-1):

$-(1-\frac{1}{N})^n \le \frac{n}{N}-1$

Sum 1 to both sides:

$1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^n \le \frac{n}{N}$

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not know Bernoulli's inequality, you can use Binomial theorem.

$$
\Big(1 - \frac{n}{N}\Big)^n = 1 - \frac{n}{N} + \binom{n}{2}\Big(\frac{n}{N}\Big)^2 - \cdots
$$

Notice that since $n$ and $N$ positive, every term of the binomial expansion is alternatively positive and negative. Because the third term is positive, truncating after the first two terms then gives

$$
\Big(1 - \frac{n}{N}\Big)^n > 1 - \frac{n}{N} 
$$